# Create a string with delimeters from fold expression

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, fold-expression

I've got the following function:

```
template<typename... Args>
void Foo(Args && ... args)
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    (stream << ... << args);
    // Do somethign with it
}
```

It can perfectly concat params into a string, but as expected it gives the output without any delimiter. Is it possible to somehow delimit the inputs from each other?

Sample output:

> elg.Debug("asd", "qwe", 123);
>
> // Prints: asdqwe123
>
> // Should prints something LIKE: asd qwe 123

Do I have to roll my own stringstream replacement for this?

Comment: If you want "output" with a specific separator, then perhaps using [`std::ostream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) would be better?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**With trailing delimiter:**

```
template<typename... Args>
void debug(Args&& ... args)
{   
    std::ostringstream stream;
    ((stream << args << ' '), ...);
}
```

**Without trailing delimiter:**

```
template<typename FirstArg, typename... Args>
void debug(FirstArg&& firstArg, Args&& ... args)
{   
    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream << firstArg;
    ((stream << ", " << args), ...);
}
```

If the race is to have the shortest code, then last two lines can be merged into one: `stream << firstArg, ((stream << ", " << args), ...);`.

---

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Args>
void debug(Args&& ... args)
{   
    ((std::cout << args << ' '), ...);
}

int main () {
    debug("asd", 112, 0.04);
    return 0;   
}
```

Output: `asd 112 0.04`

Comment: Wow, even though, this is marked as duplicate, I couldn't see anything near this useful answer around SO. Thanks, it just works perfectly!

Comment: I has small problem, `((stream << args << ','), ...)` has trailing comma at the end.

Comment: I did not understand. I think the comma at the end is correct. Ref: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold

Comment: Comma at the end is correct behavior of fold expression but not definitely what the user needs.

Comment: @ZhengQu Silly me. Thanks.